# ECSlidingViewController left and right slide

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am very new to iOS and I am trying to do simple slide left and right on my application. I use pod file to add ECSlidingViewController, however it seems to be very difficult to have slide left for menus and slide right for more options. Is it any tutorial to use them both from scratch? can you please provide me code to see how could I do it?

Comment: what are the issues you are having? what have you tried? show some code...

Comment: Thanks for your quick respond. I am trying to have a two application with main Menu on the left slide (like youtube) and for some of the menu items having right slide (like messenger in the Facebook). I am trying to follow the sample application and I am building the whole app on storyboard. How can I attach the storyboard screenshot ? my initial storyboard is the BasicMenu example, you can assume I have that

Comment: I am in the same situation and I have done it 2 months ago. Just copy paste the code for one side, but name the files/classes differently. It will work out if you try. If not, I can show you some code later in case you need it.

Comment: Thank you Andreas, Can you please send me your code? I am trying to achieve this for 3 weeks now and I couldn't. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this [iOS-Slide-Menu](https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu)

hope this will help you